# Imagick / ImagickDraw setFont and setFontFamily timing out

Tags: php, fonts, imagemagick, imagick

I have a PHP script that uses Imagick/ImageMagick to dynamically build images as required using data from a database. This has been working fine for the last few years but I restarted (after installing some OSX updates) the hardware that the site is running on earlier and all of a sudden it now won't work.

The Apache error_log file says the script is timing out on the line that calls setFont( 'Arial' ) on an ImagickDraw object. I have tried changing the parameter to the full path to the font file (/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf) but it does the same. I have also tried copying the font file to the same folder as the PHP script and loading it in using './Arial.ttf' but still the same result. If I comment out the line then the script still times out when I pass the ImagickDraw object into an Imagick->annotate_image() method (which is when I'm guessing it tries to assign a default font or similar).

After much Googling I have tried ...

- rebuilding the font cache on the OS by calling 'fc-cache'
- checking I have the correct path to the font file and that PHP can 'see' it by calling file_get_contents() on the local path and full path
- restarting the machine a few times

... but these all still time out. It seemingly just has a problem loading the fonts. My test script is:

```
$settings = new ImagickDraw();
$settings->setFillColor( '#92a7d2' );
$settings->setFontSize( 36 );
//$settings->setFont( '' ); // Throws an exception 'Can not set empty font' (as it should)
//$settings->setFont( './Arial.ttf' ); // Times out
//$settings->setFont( 'Arial' ); // Times out
//$settings->setFont( "/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf" ); // Times out
//$settings->setFontFamily( 'Arial' ); // Times out
```

Even calling \Imagick::queryFonts("*") / php_imagick_check_font() times out.

I'm at a loss now. It seems that it's to do with loading the fonts but I can't work out why and it seems odd that it should randomly appear like this.

Any ideas?

---

Result of `identify -list Configure | grep freetype` ...

CFLAGS         -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include/libpng16 -D_THREAD_SAFE -I/opt/local/include/OpenEXR -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/openjpeg-2.1 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include   -pipe -Os -arch x86_64 -Wall -mtune=sandybridge -fexceptions -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -D_THREAD_SAFE -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16
DELEGATES      bzlib djvu mpeg fftw fontconfig freetype gslib jbig jng jpeg lcms lzma openexr openjp2 png ps tiff webp x xml zlib
LIBS            -L/opt/local/lib -llcms2 -L/opt/local/lib -lfreetype   -L/opt/local/lib -lfftw3 -L/opt/local/lib -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lXext   -lSM -lICE -lX11  -lXt -L/opt/local/lib -llzma -lbz2 -L/opt/local/lib -lz -lltdl  -lm

Comment: Sounds like a freetype issue. Is ImageMagick complied against X11, or installed via HomeBrew? You can verify with `identify -list Configure | grep freetype`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added result of `identify` command to the original question. I don't know this command so not sure what is being shown .... ?